# PHP debug environment not working

Tags: php, centos, xdebug

I am at the end of my tail here and could really use some help!

Here's my setup -

- NGINX, PHP-FPM on CentOS
- Nginx conf file has the following:

  `location ~ .php$ {
  root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
  fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index   index.php;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include         fastcgi_params;
  }`
- PHP-FPM conf file at /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf has the following
  `listen=127.0.0.1:9000`

With the above configuration, NGINX can properly display PHP pages.

Now, I want to setup Xdebug. So I added the following to the /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini file

```
<code>
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=x.x.x.x
xdebug.remote_port=9009
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
</code>
```

Note remote port is set to 9009 to not conflict with the PHP-FPM port 9000.

On the x.x.x.x machine, I have XDebugClient running listening for incoming connections on port 9009.

Next, I launch a browser from the host x.x.x.x and request URL http://y.y.y.y?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1 (where y.y.y.y) is the server with the NGINX, PHP-FPM and XDebug setup.

The issue - nothing happens. XDebugClient never gets a connection!

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you restarted your server once everything is set up?

Comment: Can host reach port 9009? (nmap -p 9009 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

Comment: Yes, server was restarted - nginx and php-fpm. Also host can reach xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. In fact, I tried changing it to localhost as well and ran the Xdebug client locally and that didn't work either.

Comment: possibly explore http://serverfault.com/ stack exchange as that's more about server issues and would probably have a higher proportion of useful posts/members than SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check

- Pull up a phpinfo() page to make sure your php.ini file is configured correctly.  If you don't see a long xdebug section, then the problem is in your configuration.
- Try running a [trace](http://devzone.zend.com/1135/tracing-php-applications-with-xdebug/) or [profile](http://devzone.zend.com/1139/profiling-php-applications-with-xdebug/) with xdebug.  If they work, then the xdebug module itself is okay.
- Try setting xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 in your php.ini file.  This will override the remote_host setting and can be helpful if the problem is related to network configuration.
- Make sure your IDE is set to listen for the connection on port 9009.  In PHPStorm, for example, you must configure the IDE to listen on the custom port, and then you have to push a button to activate the debugging tool before you load the page being debugged.

Those are the basic steps I've had to go through quite a few times.  Hopefully one of them will help.

Comment: Thanks that helped narrow down the issue. In my case, I wasn't able to make the current environment work but when I created a new VM Xdebug worked right off the bat with the steps listed above.

I have the luxury of ditching my original environment, which is what I will do and move on at this point :)